Помогите пожалуйста, прошу. При нажатии кнопки на главной клавиатуре, новая inline клавиатура не добавляется, появляется только текст
#Main файл кода :


import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

from app.handlers import router


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token='токен моего бота')
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_router(router)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Бот выключен')



#handlers файл кода:




from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
import asyncio
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext

import app.keyboards as kb

router = Router()

class Change(StatesGroup):
    amount_1 = State()
    amount_2 = State()
    amount_3 = State()


amount = [20, 15, 3600]

#первая клавиатура
@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Привет!', reply_markup=kb.main)

#сменяющие ее кнопки
@router.message(F.text == 'Yescoin')
async def options(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите нужную опцию', гeply_markup=kb.options)

#Острочка времени до прихода уведомления
    @router.message(F.text == 'Запустить таймер')
    async def options1(message: Message):
        await message.answer('Таймер запущен' ,  reply_markup=kb.main)
        await asyncio.sleep(amount[0])
        await message.answer('Время майнить Yescoin')

#возможность изменить время таймера на заданное пользователем число в секундах
    @router.message(F.text == 'Изменить время таймера')
    async def options2(message: Message):
        await message.answer('Изменить время таймера для Yescoin')

        @router.message(Change.amount_1)
        async def Change_chislo(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
            await state.update_data(amount=message.text)
            global amount
            try:
                amount[0] = int(message.text.strip())
            except ValueError:
                await message.answer('Неверный формат. Впишите число')
                await state.set_state(Change.amount_1)
                return
            await message.answer('Время таймера успешно изменено')


#Далее код повторяется для кождой кнопки главной клавиатуры
@router.message(F.text == 'Mine POO')
async def options3(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите нужную опцию', гeply_markup=kb.options)

    @router.message(F.text == 'Запустить таймер')
    async def options4(message: Message):
        await message.answer('Таймер запущен', reply_markup=kb.main)
        await asyncio.sleep(amount[1])
        await message.answer('Время майнить Mine POO')

    @router.message(F.text == 'Изменить время таймера')
    async def options5(message: Message):
        await message.answer('Изменить время таймера для Mine POO')

        @router.message(Change.amount_2)
        async def Change_chislo_1(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
            await state.update_data(amount=message.text)
            global amount
            try:
                amount[1] = int(message.text.strip())
            except ValueError:
                await message.answer('Неверный формат. Впишите число')
                await state.set_state(Change.amount_2)
                return
            await message.answer('Время таймера успешно изменено')

@router.message(F.text == 'MemeFi Coin')
async def options6(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите нужную опцию', гeply_markup=kb.options)

    @router.message(F.text == 'Запустить таймер')
    async def options7(message: Message):
        await message.answer('Таймер запущен', reply_markup=kb.main)
        await asyncio.sleep(amount[2])
        await message.answer('Время майнить MemeFi Coin')

    @router.message(F.text == 'Изменить время таймера')
    async def options8(message: Message):
        await message.answer('Изменить время таймера для MemeFi Coin')

        @router.message(Change.amount_3)
        async def Change_chislo_2(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
            await state.update_data(amount=message.text)
            global amount
            try:
                amount[2] = int(message.text.strip())
            except ValueError:
                await message.answer('Неверный формат. Впишите число')
                await state.set_state(Change.amount_3)
                return
            await message.answer('Время таймера успешно изменено')

#keyboards файл кода:

from aiogram.types import (ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton)

main = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[[KeyboardButton(text='Yescoin')],
                                        [KeyboardButton(text='Mine POO')],
                                        [KeyboardButton(text='PocketFi'),
                                         KeyboardButton(text='MemeFi Coin')]],
                           resize_keyboard=True,
                           input_field_placeholder='Выберите кликер...')

options = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='Запустить таймер', callback_data='start_timer')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='Изменить время таймера', callback_data='change_timer')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вернуться в главное меню', callback_data='back')]])```




